# How to use typedef to create multiple arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, typedef, preprocessor

I'm modifying decounce code for a push button system, where momentary buttons will be monitored for a short press and a long press to carry out some action. I'm having trouble using the code in Typedef though as it seems to not be working as I expect. Can anyone help explain what I'm missing? Specifically, I'm modifying the code to work for multiple buttons.

In the setup I have 'buttons[i].dimmer = dimmer[i];' using the "buttons[i].dimmer" I thought was established in the typedef but I can't seem to populate it? When I run the code no inputs are read, I'm trying to sort out what may have happened here.

Full code:

```
// detectButtonPress
// Use millis to detect a short and long button press
// See baldengineer.com/detect-short-long-button-press-using-millis.html for more information
// Created by James Lewis

#define PRESSED LOW
#define NOT_PRESSED HIGH

int value = 0;
const byte numberButtons = 5;
const int debounce = 10;
int pin[numberButtons] = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8}; //not used with multiple buttons?**
int dimmer[numberButtons] = {A0, A1, A0, A0, 0};  //which dimmer is associated with which button
int output[numberButtons]  = {10, 10, 11, 11, 0};   //which output pin to send signal
//variables for timing long button press
unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long timerMillis;
const unsigned long period = 4000;  //the value is a number of milliseconds, ie 4000=4 second
int longPressOutput = 0;    //which dimmer to monitor with long press
int longPressDimmer = 0;    //dimmer pin for long press

const unsigned long shortPress = 100;
const unsigned long  longPress = 500;
bool monitorDimmer = false;       //whether to monitor dimmer or not

int dimValue = 0;         //dimmer value initialized

typedef struct Buttons {
    const int debounce = 10;
    unsigned long counter=0;
    bool prevState = NOT_PRESSED;
    bool currentState;
    bool lightState = false;
    bool prevLightState = false;

    int pin[numberButtons] = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8}; //not used with multiple buttons?**
    int dimmer[numberButtons] = {A0, A1, A0, A0, 0};  //which dimmer is associated with which button
    int output[numberButtons]  = {10, 10, 11, 11, 0};   //which output pin to send signal

} Button;

     //array of button objects
    Buttons buttons[numberButtons];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  //start Serial in case we need to print debugging info
  startMillis = millis();  //initial start time
  bool monitorDimmer = false;  //initial monitorDimmer status

  //initialize each button in the array
  for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons; i++) {
    buttons[i].pin = pin[i];            //initialize pin number for this buttons
    buttons[i].dimmer = dimmer[i];
    buttons[i].output = output[i];      //this one doesn't work but the above does?
    buttons[i].debounce = debounce;
    pinMode(buttons[i].pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    //Serial.println(buttons[i].pin);
  }
}

void loop() {

  timerMillis = millis();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberButtons; i++) {
    // check the button
    buttons[i].currentState = digitalRead(buttons[i].pin);

    // has it changed?
      if (buttons[i].currentState != buttons[i].prevState) {
        delay(buttons[i].debounce);
        // update status in case of bounce
        buttons[i].currentState = digitalRead(buttons[i].pin);
        if (buttons[i].currentState == PRESSED) {
            // a new press event occured
            // record when button went down
            buttons[i].counter = millis();
        }

        if (buttons[i].currentState == NOT_PRESSED) {
            // but no longer pressed, how long was it down?
            unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
            if ((currentMillis - buttons[i].counter >= shortPress) && !(currentMillis - buttons[i].counter >= longPress)) {
                // short press detected. 
                buttons[i].prevLightState = buttons[i].lightState;  //Set prev to current, then change
                buttons[i].lightState != buttons[i].lightState;     //flip state
                if (buttons[i].lightState = true) {
                  analogWrite(buttons[i].output, 180);    //set pin to roughly 70% brightness**
                  value = 5;
                  Serial.println(value);
                }else   {
                  analogWrite(buttons[i].output, 0);
                  value = 4;
                  Serial.println(value);
                  }
                  //specifically for off button - above will only turn off pin 10, this gets pin 11
                  if (i == 4) {
                  analogWrite(11, 0);       
                  }
            }
            if ((currentMillis - buttons[i].counter >= longPress)) {
                // the long press was detected
                analogWrite(buttons[i].pin, 180);           //turn light on immediately
                longPressDimmer = buttons[i].dimmer;        //set monitor value for dimmer pin
                longPressOutput = buttons[i].output;           //set which output to watch
                startMillis = millis();
                monitorDimmer = true;         //set true so dimmer loop
                //handleLongPress();          //go to long press function to monitor dimmer
                  //specifically for off button - above will only turn off pin 10, this gets pin 11
                  if (i == 4) {
                  analogWrite(11, 0);       //turn off main
                  analogWrite(10, 0);       //turn off bed
                  }
            }
        }
        // used to detect when state changes
        buttons[i].prevState = buttons[i].currentState;
    } 
}

if (monitorDimmer == true) {
  if (timerMillis - startMillis <= period) { //until period is reached do this
  dimValue = analogRead(longPressDimmer);
  analogWrite(longPressOutput,dimValue);      //set light to value of dimmer
  }
  else {
  monitorDimmer = false;                    //if time is up, stop checking
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have "numberButtons" buttons each with "numberButtons" outputs. This means you have numberButtons*numberButtons outputs, which sounds wrong. If this is what is intended, you would need a loop like this

```
for (int b_idx = 0; b_idx < numberButtons; ++b_idx)  // once per button
    for (int o_idx = 0; o_idx < numberButtons; ++o_idx)    // once per button
         button[b_idx].output[o_idx] = init_value;
```

However, from the comments in the code it is entirely more likely your error really is in your structure

```
struct Button { 
    const int debounce = 10;
    unsigned long counter=0;
    bool prevState = NOT_PRESSED;
    bool currentState;
    bool lightState = false;
    bool prevLightState = false;

    int pin {-1};  // Each button has only one pin
    int dimmer {-1}; // Each button has only one dimmer
    int output {-1}; // Each button has only one output
};
//array of button objects
Button buttons[numberButtons];
```

Now your setup function make sense.

Comment: You were right! The structure was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of, the `typedef` isn’t need in C++! That’s a C thing. It is allowed but actually doesn’t really have any useful effect.

It seems you are trying to create a class and hope to initialize a global array to reference the elements in the class. That won’t work as C++ is based on *values* rather than references. You could potentially use pointers in your class to point to the global array to modify these.

Answer (score 0):

**constexpr**  or **template**
not typedef

```
// ...
#include <windows.h> // for byte type:
const byte numberButtons = 5;

// ...

int dimValue = 0;         //dimmer value initialized

template<byte DIM>
struct Buttons {
    const int debounce = 10;
    unsigned long counter=0;
    bool prevState = NOT_PRESSED;
    bool currentState;
    bool lightState = false;
    bool prevLightState = false;

    int pin[DIM] = {2, 3, 4, 7, 8}; //not used with multiple buttons?**
    int dimmer[DIM] = {A0, A1, A0, A0, 0};  //which dimmer is associated with which button
    int output[DIM]  = {10, 10, 11, 11, 0};   //which output pin to send signal

}
typedef Buttons<numberButtons> BUT;

int main ( ) {

   //array of button objects
   BUT buttons;

 for (int i=0; i<15; ++i)
    cout<< buttons.pin[i] <<"\n";
}
```